# Issue updating span content in a row of spans with jQuery by toggling contentEditable

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I have a div which contains multiple spans. When a user clicks on the span, it should become editable. This part is working fine but when someone tries to edit the content in it, the problems begin.

- The first character can't be removed
- Can't press backspace more than once, the user needs to get the cursor back to the span after pressing backspace once.
- If there is only one character remaining, it can be removed but then the span disappears.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="entries">
  <p class="entry">
    <span class="name">Taj</span>
    <span class="city">Havelock</span>
    <span class="price">10000.00</span>
    <span class="updaterow" style="visibility: hidden;"><a href="#">Save</a></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

and the JS

```
$('.entries').on('click','span', function() {
 $(this).attr('contentEditable', true);
 $(this).siblings('.updaterow').css('visibility','visible');
}).on('focusout','span',function() {
 $(this).attr('contentEditable', false);    
 $(this).siblings('.updaterow').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

and here's the same things on jsfiddle to see how it works http://jsfiddle.net/VjUfZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use inline-block instead of inline-table

```
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VjUfZ/2/

Comment: That fixed the problem. If somebody can explain why inline-table causes this problem that would be even more awesome. In the meanwhile I will go read about inline-table by myself too.